# how i finish current component on button click in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have created two component ( A and B) and put it inside StackNavigator after that header set to null then it's header not showing . so i created custom header for B component with back arrow. so my question is when i push Component B from A and click Back Arrow then Component B will finished like android finish() method .

thanks

Comment: may be you are looking for [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Comment: @JigarShah : thanks for reply but  Back Arrow is custom Image Button in Component B then how i call  componentDidMount on ImageButton onPress please suggest .